# Flexibility of long-chain aliphatic compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, conformers

PubChem is unable to generate the conformers of [*Z*-6-Heneicosen-11-one](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Z_-6-Heneicosen-11-one)? The website says that the molecule is **too flexible**

**What does flexibility of a molecule mean in this context**? I understand that it is a long chain compound, but I assumed that the bonds are rigid and do not flex? In layman’s terms, how does one quantify flexibility? Is it flexible like a skipping rope or like something else?

Comment: The bonds are rigid, but the torsion angles aren't.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/125574/5017

Comment: Rather than to flexible it want to say too much atoms /bonds

Comment: @Alchimista - it's not that it has too many atoms or bonds. A rigid molecule with the same number of atoms will appear (e.g, [cholesterol](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/5997#section=Structures) is okay).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**PubChem 3D has limits on the number of 'rotatable bonds'**

I recently answered a related question about [PubChem 3D](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/125591/5017):

> Beyond the limits of MMFF94 and MMFF94s themselves, PubChem3D had several limits indicated in the accompanying manuscript: [Bolton et. al. "PubChem3D: a new resource for scientists" *J Cheminf.* (2011) v. 3, art. 32)](https://doi.org//10.1186/1758-2946-3-32)
>
> - Not too large (with ≤ 50 non-hydrogen atoms).
> - Not too flexible (with ≤ 15 rotatable bonds).
> - Consists of only supported elements (H, C, N, O, F, Si, P, S, Cl, Br, and I).
> - Has only a single covalent unit (i.e., not a salt or a mixture).
> - Contains only atom types recognized by the MMFF94s force field.
> - Has fewer than six undefined atom or bond stereo centers.

Your molecule falls into the "more than 15 rotatable bonds" category. I count about 18 $\ce{sp^3}-\ce{sp^3}$ single bonds.

Basically, the problem is that the search space for conformers with that many rotatable bonds is too big. In principal, it's $\approx3^n$ where $n$ is the number of rotatable bonds.